# Transparent background for label of shape using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create shapes using vba. Shape has a label but i want the label box to have transparent background. Tried the code below but I get object required error.

```
Sub obj()
   ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddLabel(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, c, r, l1 / 4, h1 / 4).TextFrame.Characters.Text = l1 & "->"

     With TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Fill
         .Transparency = 0.9
     End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the shape to format it.
First add the shape and specify it's name:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddLabel(msoTextOrientationHorizontal,  c, r, l1 / 4, h1 / 4).Name = "ExampleName"
```

Then you can format it anyway you want:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ExampleName").TextFrame.Characters.Text = l1 & "->"
ActiveSheet.Shapes("ExampleName").Fill.Transparency = 0.9
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm actually working with many shapes and defining them individually might be too tedious. I have below code for both the shape and label ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, c, r, l1, h1)
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddLabel(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, c, r, l1 / 2, h1 / 2).TextFrame.Characters.Text = l1 & "->" and then a For loop for number of items required.

Comment: Create a rule for them and use a `For... Next` statement. You'll find that you could create an enormous number of shapes with only a few lines of code.

Comment: will consider these. Thank you!